# What is the obstruction to the existence of a global Kahler potential?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

It is a well-know fact that if $(X,\omega)$ is Kahler then about every point $x \in X$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ and a function $K \in C^{\infty}(U,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\omega|_U = i\partial \bar{\partial} K$. Here $K$ is called a local Kahler potential.

My question is when does this extend globally, i.e. what conditions must be imposed on a Kahler manifold $(X,\omega)$ so that there exists a function $K \in C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\omega = i \partial \bar{\partial} K$? Clearly being non-compact is one condition and there are certainly examples of such manifolds ($\mathbb{C}^n$ etc.). I am guessing there is some vanishing theorem on Dolbeault cohomology but cannot find it in the literature

Comment: The "standard textbook" proof shows that if $[\omega]=0$ in $H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ and if $H^{0,1}_{\bar\partial}(X)$ vanishes, then you can write $\omega=i\partial\bar\partial K$. You can easily reconstruct the proof by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the lines of vanishing conditions you can argue as follows. Let $U_\alpha$ be a collection of patches such that $\omega=i\partial\bar\partial f_\alpha$ for some $f_\alpha\in C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb R)$. Then the collection of differences $\{f_\alpha-f_\beta\}$ gives you a Cech cocycle $\phi\in C^1(M,\mathcal P)$, where $\mathcal P$ is a sheaf of real pluriharmonic functions (i.e. satisfying the equation $\partial\bar\partial g=0$). You wish to show that this cocycle is zero in the cohomology group.

Locally any pluriharmonic function is a real part of holomorphic function, so we have a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb R\to \mathcal O\xrightarrow{Re}\mathcal P\to 0,
$$
We get LES in cohomology
$$
\dots\to H^1(M,\mathcal O)\to H^1(M,\mathcal P)\xrightarrow{\delta} H^2(M,\mathbb R)\to\dots
$$
Since $\delta([\phi])=[\omega]$, as you have mentioned, the first thing you require is $[\omega]=0$.

Now, given that $[\omega]=0$, it is enough to assume that $H^1(M,\mathcal O)=0$.

**Remark.** Note that in a non-compact case the vanishing $H^1(M,\mathcal O)=0$ is not implied by $\pi_1(M)=1$, for example, the group $H^1(\mathbb C^2\backslash(0,0),\mathcal O)$ has infinite dimension.

This example allows you to construct a (not necessarily positive) real closed 2-form $\gamma$, which has a local potential, but does not have global. Namely, take a representative $\alpha^{0,1}$ of a nonzero class in $H^1(\mathbb C^2\backslash(0,0),\mathcal O)$ and consider $\gamma=Re(\partial\alpha^{0,1})$ (or $Im(\partial\alpha^{0,1})$).

Comment: Nice example, Here you mean Kahler current or Kahler forms? Can you specify

Comment: No, I do not consider currents here, though after certain modifications the argument might work. In the example $\gamma$ is merely a closed real 2-form and is not necessarily Kahler. By the way, having this example in mind, I find the statement in the first quote in your answer a  bit confusing. Do you have a proof in mind?

Comment: I know that for non-compact homogeneous manifolds global potential is related to topological candition that manifold must be contractible but I don't have any proof for my first statement. My conjecture is that global potential must be related to some correction in geometric quantization.

Comment: In Sasakian cone which is kahler manifold, we have global Kahler potential also and these spaces are good examples for global Kahler potential.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the answer I am after. Could you expand (i.e. spell out the argument) on why $\phi$ must be zero in cohomology. I only know a bit of sheaf cohomology and used the top answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125200/coboundaries-and-gluing-in-cech-cohomology-intuition for an intuitive idea of the first cohomology group of the kernel of a surjective morphism $F \to F''$. Hence $\phi$ being a coboundary means that we can lift a global section of $F''$ to one of $F$, but fail to see what $F$ and $F''$ are in this case (although guess $F$ is the sheaf of potentials).

Comment: You can take $F$ to be a sheaf of smooth functions (potentials) and $F''$ to a be a sheaf of closed smooth (1,1)-forms with a surjective map $\partial\bar\partial\colon F\to F''$. The kernel of this map is precisely the sheaf of pluriharmonic functions $\mathcal P$ and the obstruction to the lift of a global section from $F''$ to $F$ lives in $H^1(M,\mathcal P)$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But is the argument that you can lift a global section $\omega = \partial \bar{\partial} K \in F''(X)$ if and only if $[\phi]=0$ the same thing as saying that there exists a global $\omega$ if and only if $[\phi]=0$? Moreover I'm not sure why the SES you give is exact nor why $\delta([\phi]) = [\omega]$. Sorry for being slow, I just want to make sure that I understand everything properly.

Answer (score 5):

> In this book Geometric and Algebraic Topological Methods in Quantum
>   Mechanics, G. Giachetta,L. Mangiarotti,Gennadiĭ Aleksandrovich
>   Sardanashvili page 181
>
> in remark 2.6.2, it has been written that if $X $ be a simply
>   connected non-compact manifold then then local Kahler potential can be
>   glued into global one, and if $X$ is not simply connected then local
>   potential still exists on an open subset $U$ obtained from $X$ by
>   deleting a real submanifold of lower dimension

Recently [A. Loi showed that](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00011)

Let$ (M, ω) $ be a homogeneous Kahler manifold. Then the following
are equivalent:

(a)$ M$ is contractible.

(b)$ (M, ω)$ admits a global Kahler potential.

(c) $(M, ω) $admits a Berezin quantization.

If $\omega$ is a real  $d$-exact $(1,1)$-form, then $\omega$ is $\sqrt{-1}∂∂$-exact , i.e. there exits a real
function $u$ such that locally $\omega = i∂∂u$

> If $ M$ is a compact Kahler manifold then $M$ cannot have a global
>   Kahler potential.see page 6 [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/rjain/CalabiConjecture.pdf)

In general Gauduchon showed that for a compact complex manifold $M$, $dd^c$
-lemma for $(1, 1)$-forms
is equivalent to the equality $b^1 = 2h^{0,1}$.

> Deligne  showed that Complex manifolds satisfying the $dd^c$-lemma
>   are formal [see New aspects of the ddc
>   -lemma](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501406.pdf)

=========

> If $\omega$ be a Kahler current instead of Kahler form, then still
>   $dd^c $
>   -lemma holds

=========

> Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. The equality
>
> $$\sum_{p+q=k}(dim_\mathbb
>  CH_{BC}^{p,q}(X)+dim_A^{p,q}(X))=2dim_\mathbb CH_{dR}^k(X,\mathbb C)$$
>   holds for every $k \in N$ if and only if $X$ satisfies the
>   $∂\bar∂$-Lemma. here , $H_{BC}^{•,•} (X)$, is Bott-Chern  and
>   $H^{•,•}_A(X) $ is Aeppli cohomologies.

**In Sasakian cone we have global Kahler potential:**

A compact Riemannian manifold $(S,g)$ is Sasakian if and only if its metric cone $(C(S)=R_{>0}\times S, \bar g=dr^2+r^2g)$ is Kahler. which Sasakian manifolds are the odd dimentional view of Kahler manifolds

Then if $S$ be Sasakian, then the cone $C(S)$ has

$$\omega=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt {-1}\partial\bar\partial r^2$$

the function $\frac{1}{2}r^2$ is hence a **global Kahler potential** for the cone metric

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't really answer the question. As we both said, compact Kahler manifolds cannot admit a global Kahler potential and so I am interested in the case when $(X,\omega)$ is exact. I don't know whether your first statement applies in this case.

Comment: I edited it , I added some references

Comment: The statement of the result of Gauduchon is wrong, it should say $b^1=2h^{0,1}$.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07421.pdf Theorem 4.1, can you give a reason, I don't see it

Comment: There is a typo in the paper. $\dim H^1(X,\mathcal O)$ is $h^{0,1}$.

Comment: @Hassan Jolany 海桑乔朗丽 Never trust blindly any paper, unless you have checked the details yourself!

Comment: Let $X$ be a complex manifold with $H_1(X,\mathbb R) = 0$. Then $X$
satisfies the $∂\bar ∂$-lemma if and only if $H^1(X, \mathcal O) = 0.$ see Proposition 3.10 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.0186.pdf and also https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00005850

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact complex manifolds,
and $ f : X → Y$ a holomorphic (birational) surjective morphism. Id the $\partial\bar \partial$-lemma holds for $X$, then it holds for $Y$. But I don't think the inverse hold.  This is due to deep result of  P. Deligne, 1968 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02698925

Comment: The previous comment says that if a compact complex manifold $X$ be birational to a Kahler manifold, then we still have $ ∂\bar ∂$-lemma even $X$ not be Kahler

Answer (score 0):

Here's a geometric way to think about the obstruction. Consider a holomorphic line bundle $L$ over a complex manifold $M$ and let $h \in \Gamma\big(\overline{L}\,^*\otimes L^*\big)$ be a Hermitian form on it. With respect to a local holomorphic trivialisation, we may write $h$ as $e^{f}$ for some function $f$ on an open set in $M$. Then the Chern connection is given by $\mathrm d + \partial f = \overline \partial + \partial + \partial f$ in the local holomorphic trivialisation we have chosen and its curvature is $\mathrm d \partial f = \overline \partial \partial f$. We thus see that the Kähler potential $f$ associated to a Kähler form $\omega$ is locally the logarithm of the Hermitian form $h$ on a holomorphic line bundle $L$ whose associated Chern curvature is (up to an overall constant factor) $\omega$ itself.

The function $e^{f}$ is globally defined if and only if (a) $L$ is trivial as a complex line bundle, and (b) the holomorphic structure on $L$ is trivial. These are guaranteed by the conditions $[\omega]=0$ and $H^1(M;\mathscr O^\times)=0$ respectively. Now, keeping in mind the exponential sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow \mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathscr O \longrightarrow \mathscr O^\times \longrightarrow 0$$

we note that $H^1(M;\mathscr O^\times)=0$ by itself doesn't guarantee that the *logarithm* $f$ is globally defined. The stronger condition $H^1(M;\mathscr O)=0$ however ensures this.