# Why should the Kaehler form be closed?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, kahler-differentials

As the question says, why should the Kaehler form be closed? Like people start from a fundamental 2-form (say, a 2-from $\mathcal{K}$) and then set they set the condition that in order for the manifold with a hermitian metric to be Kaehler, its 2-from must be closed, i.e $d\mathcal{K}=0$. Why is that?

Comment: Because we want a symplectic form. (And this lead to the question: why a symplectic form should be closed?)

Comment: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~kahlergeometry/Yau_Talk.pdf

Comment: We want locally write our form as$ i\partial\bar \partial u$ this means exactly closedness

Comment: A definition often arises from an abstraction of interesting examples. One motivation for the Kähler form comes from complex projective space and complex submanifolds (which are also algebraic varieties). The Kähler form is very natural in that setting because it is defined in terms of the natural Riemannian metric and generates the cohomology of $\mathbb{C}P^n$. This leads to a rich interaction between the topology, differential geometric, and algebraic geometric properties of the variety. It then becomes natural to study Kähler manifolds in general.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. If you have a Hermitian manifold, then the metric and the complex structure define a natural $(1,1)$-form. The definition of a Kähler manifold is that it is a Hermitian manifold where the naturally defined $(1,1)$-form is closed. Or are you using a different definition?

Comment: @physicsoutsideborders It is just the definition of a Kaehler manifold.  Why do we study them?  Because they are an interesting special case.  Why?  Because here are all these fundamental examples.

Comment: But as Steven Gubkin says, it's the definition.

Comment: You don't have to demand the form be closed, in fact there are several generalisations of Kahler geometry where it isn't. But if it is closed, many nice things happen, and we call it a Kahler manifold. Why do you need more than that?

Comment: Check here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329342/what-exactly-is-a-k%C3%A4hler-manifold MBM's answer last paragraph. They say "Saying that the Kahler form is closed actually converts it into a symplectic form which fits nicely with the Kahler structure, so all the tools of the vastly developed subject of symplectic geometry can be made to bear. You can look up what makes the symplectic form so important." So how true is that and what is meant by fits nicely? @PaulReynolds

Comment: Qfwfq's comment is that you want a symplectic form. That's equivalent to saying you want the $(1,1)$-form to be closed.

Comment: It should be noted that Kähler geometry is quite different and historically did not use much symplectic geometry. As far as I know, the sympectic geometry, which is a very "flabby" structure (for example, there are no local invariants), of closed manifolds became an active area of research only after Gromov and others found global invariants to study. On the other hand, Kähler geometry is a more rigid geometry; it has local invariants, notably curvature, which can be integrated to obtain global invariants. The closedness of the Kähler form means that these invariants are often topological.

Comment: @physicsoutsideborders: I thought I tried to answer that in my first comment. I've added more in my last comment before this one.

Answer (score 2):

I heard from Professor Yau in his talk in Nashville see [here in page 3](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~kahlergeometry/Yau_Talk.pdf)

By looking at the example of
the Poincare metric, Kahler demands the Hermitian form to be
closed. And he derived that locally, such a form must be $i\partial\bar\partial u$
of
some potential.

if you take $\omega=\sum_{i,j}g_{i,j}dz_i\wedge d\bar z_j$ then $d\omega=0$ exactly means

$$\frac{\partial g_{i\bar j}}{\partial z_k}=\frac{\partial g_{k\bar j}}{\partial z_i}$$

In page 6 of Catherine Cannizzo [lecture note](https://math.berkeley.edu/~jhicks/links/SOTS/ccannizzo020514.pdf) you can find the geometric meaning of closedness of a Kahler form

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913828/equivalence-between-k%C3%A4hler-condition-and-partial-kg-i-bar-j-partial-ig

Comment: open the link , you will see. I think you are beginner , you can ask such questions in math.stackexchange

Comment: it is a theorem you can find it in books related to Kahler geometry

Comment: If you ask when locally such functions could be written globally then here is something http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221615/what-is-the-obstruction-to-the-existence-of-a-global-kahler-potential/221624#221624

Comment: I must sleep now, it is à simple exercice

Comment: @physicsoutsideborders, note $\mathcal{K}(u, v) = g(u, Jv)$ where $J$ is the complex structure.

Comment: $J$ is an endomorphism of the (real) tangent space that makes it into a complex space, whence it corresponds to multiplication by $i$. I think you'll get a better reception for these kind of questions over at math.stackexchange and probably there are some questions already there of interest to you.