# When are Kähler potentials bounded from below?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

The prototypical example of global Kähler potential is the one of the standard Kähler structure on $\Bbb C^n$ given by
$$f:\Bbb C^n\longrightarrow \Bbb R,\quad f(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n|z_k|^2.$$
An obvious property that one observe is that $f$ is bounded from below.

> **Question:** Are there known conditions to ensure a global Kähler potential on a (non-compact) Kähler manifold is bounded from below?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221615/what-is-the-obstruction-to-the-existence-of-a-global-kahler-potential/221624#221624

Comment: on compact manifolds global Kähler potential  does not exists, you must edit your post

Comment: What do you expect to gain from the potential being bounded below?

Comment: I'm skeptical that knowing that a potential is bounded gives any information about the metric. Roughly, the metric is the second derivatives of the potential, and knowing that a function is bounded has never helped me estimate its derivatives. Also, on a Stein manifold, the reverse is uninformative: any Kahler metric that admits a global potential admits an unbounded potential: Embed the manifold in $\mathbb C^n$, take your potential $f$ and add $\operatorname{Re} g$ for any holomorphic function $g$ (exp of a coordinate, for example). You can make that as unbounded as you want.